# WordPress Media Library Issue

Tags: wordpress

I've uploaded my images using the WordPress Media Library. Permissions are set on the Uploads directory. Images are showing up in the proper uploads directory and re-sized correctly. Database is updated correctly and has proper path to images.

When in the media library, I see the thumbnails to the images, but when I click on a thumbnail to view the image, it doesn't display the image at all. Nothing shows up.

I've also tried using these images in an image slider and when i browse the media library, it finds them. I select the image to use in my slider and the thumbnail of the selected image gets displayed fine, but when I view my slider from the web page the image doesn't get displayed there either. Just an empty slider.

I have no plugins activated at all.

I'm using the Bizniz theme purchased off Themeforest.

I've updated WordPress to 3.3.2

Running off my local machine using Apache.

When i copy the image path from the database and paste it into the browser, the image gets displayed fine.

Everything is working except for the images. Any help is really appreciated!

**UPDATE:** 
Ok, i tried switching my theme back to Twenty Eleven and then clicked my media library thumbnails and the images are displaying correctly. So it looks like it has something to do with the Bizniz theme i'm using. Is it possibly a jquery conflict or something? Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks again!
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've found a "temporary" solution to the problem. It seems the issue is with the version of TimThumb (which was v2.8.10 installed with the Bizniz theme).

I ended up using an older version (1.14) in place of this new version and it seems to have resolved the issue.

Although this has resolved the issue, i'm saying "temporary" as i'm not sure what features i might be missing between the two versions and am hoping the new version gets updated to correct this issue.